# Connect to Oracle On-premise from Cloud via VPN

Tags: ibm-cloud, oracle12c

Is there a particular configuration to allow access to an Oracle 12c database on-premise via the VPN?
I am trying to access an Oracle 12c database (on-premise, on my Virtual Box) from the IBM Cloud (AppConnect) using the Secure Gateway Client.
I'm sure the credentials are correct (the ones I use for SQL developer). The VPN is connected and well configured.
But the connection cannot be established with the only message: "Check the values you have entered are correct"!

A second question, please, how to enable Oracle traces to see attempts connection errors?

Thank you

Comment: So you started the SG client on your Oracle box and it established a connection to IBM Cloud?

Comment: I start the client SG on my VM (containing oracle) and I try to access Oracle from the cloud (already containing the VPN server).

Comment: and the connection is shown as established? Are the Oracle and VPN ports open and not blocked by any firewall on the host?

Comment: I disabled the firewalls. 
The only traces on the VPN are : 
[ 01/10/2020 at 11:43:31 ] [ INFO ]: Connection #55 is being established to 192.168.56.126:1521
[ 01/10/2020 at 11:43:31 ] [ DEBUGING ]: Connection #55 established to 192.168.56.126:1521
[ 01/10/2020 at 11:43:31 ] [ DEBUGING ]: Connection #55 to 192.168.56.126:1521 has ended
[ 01/10/2020 at 11:43:31 ] [ INFO ]: Connection #55 to 192.168.56.126:1521 was closed